# Adding a Wordpress Blog in a .Net Website

Tags: .net, wordpress, blogs

This is my first project and I have been asked to use WordPress to create a blog that is embedded in a .Net Website using SQL Server.

Now my question is as follows

- Can it Be Done ?
- If yes How can I do it ? ( Any link that can guide will be great )
- If not any ideas what can I do ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What does "embedded" mean? Same server? Same links? Same domain?

Comment: I mean on Same Domain & Server

Answer (score 1):

WordPress requires PHP and MySQL. You can run it on the same server as your .NET application, but you cannot run it without PHP and MySQL.

Here's instructions for setting up Wordpress in IIS.

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-wordpress-on-iis

However, I'd personally prefer a sub-domain so you can be more flexible in the future to support having them on the same server, or on different servers, and even have them on separate hosts.